# How can I make a discord bot creates a channel on a command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

**Hello there**

I'm currently working on a discord server called "file storing" (name is subject to change)
and I'm wondering if there is a way that: when a user types a certain command such as ">fs create"
the bot creates a channel like "channelid-storing" that is only visible to the user that used the command?

Channel name format is going to show the channels id then "-storing"

````
let client = new Discord.Client()

client.on("message", message => {
  if(message.content === "ping") {
    message.channel.send("pong")
}
  
  client.on(message, async (message) => {
    if(message === `>fs create`){
   const channel = await message.guild.channels.create("channel", {
            permissionOverwrites: [
                {
                    id: message.guild.roles.everyone,
                    deny: ["VIEW_CHANNEL"],
                },
                {
                    id: message.member,
                     allow: [
                        "VIEW_CHANNEL",
                        "SEND_MESSAGES",
                        "EMBED_LINKS",
                        "ATTACH_FILES",
                        "READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY",
                    ],
                },
                {
                    id: message.guild.me, 
                    allow: [
                        "VIEW_CHANNEL",
                        "SEND_MESSAGES",
                        "EMBED_LINKS",
                        "ATTACH_FILES",
                        "READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY",
                    ],
                },
            ],
        });
    channel.editName(`${channel.id}-store`)

}
})
    
})

client.login(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN);```
````

Answer (score 1):

You just have to supply user permissions, when creating the channel

```js
if(commandname === `> fs create`){
   const channel = await message.guild.channels.create("channelname", {
            permissionOverwrites: [
                {
                    id: message.guild.roles.everyone,
                    deny: ["VIEW_CHANNEL"],
                },
                {
                    id: message.member,
                     allow: [
                        "VIEW_CHANNEL",
                        "SEND_MESSAGES",
                        "EMBED_LINKS",
                        "ATTACH_FILES",
                        "READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY",
                    ],
                },
                {
                    id: message.guild.me, 
                    allow: [
                        "VIEW_CHANNEL",
                        "SEND_MESSAGES",
                        "EMBED_LINKS",
                        "ATTACH_FILES",
                        "READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY",
                    ],
                },
            ],
        });
    channel.editName(`${channel.id}-store`)

}
```

Btw, you have to add your stuff, so that it properly works, the example above, shows how the channel creating works..

Comment: Vote up for meiser mate

Comment: @Meister9667 But how would I make the channel automatically get named as channelid-storing with channelid being the actuall channel's id

Comment: The only way is to await it, through `const channel = await channelcreate....` and then edit the name with channel.editName(`${channel.id}-storing`)

Comment: can you tell me how to format that in your code? sorry I'm a beginner, I can only really do things like simple reply commands without a tut @Meister9667

Comment: @Meister9667 it says "Parsing Error: Cannot use keyword 'await' outside an async function

Comment: you have to run your code in a async funtion. Based on your experience I would guess that you are doing `client.on(message)`, do `client.on(message, async (message) => {})`

Comment: @Meister9667 from there, how do I set my command back to be `>fs create`. from what i see i can't set a command to trigger the async

Comment: or could i use `if(message.content === "")`

Comment: @Meister9667 okay i did everything the way you told me to but now it doesn't even create a channel

Comment: any errors? did it worked without the await?

Comment: @Meister9667 No errors. it just doesn't create a channel, i have edited my question to include the code.

Comment: @Meister9667 can you revert your code to its original state? I figure I don't need id's